# Why there is no airport IATA code XXX?

Tags: iata

It seems that there is no XXX IATA code: from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_by_IATA_code:_X), XVL (Vinh Long, Vietnam) is followed by XYA (Yandina, Solomon Islands). There is a [source](http://airport-codes.wanderbat.com/l/14254/Mena-AR-Mena-Intermountain-Municipal) claiming that XXX used to refer to Mena Intermountain Municipal Airport, but from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mena_Intermountain_Municipal_Airport) this place seems (rather strangely) to have no IATA code at all (and a [source](http://www.gcmap.com/airport/KMEZ) for this claim is given).

What are the reasons for not having the XXX IATA code? Is this a reserved combination? Has it belonged to the Mena Airport in the past, and if so, why has it been deregistered on October 21, 2014, as the source claims?

Comment: There are plenty of three-letter combinations that are not IATA airport codes. Why do you think XXX might be special?

Comment: I often refer to McCarren International Airport as ***XXX***.

Comment: XXX looks like a placeholder.

Comment: Based on the IATA site Pondlife linked in [his answer](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/27591/5517), DDD, EEE, FFF, III, JJJ, NNN, OOO, QQQ, VVV, WWW, and ZZZ aren't currently assigned, so there's nothing special about 3-of-the-same-letter combinations being used, either. In all, there are 17,576 available 3 letter combinations, so it's not surprising that they haven't all been assigned.

Comment: Also, if you look at the "Overview" panel of information at your `source` that claims it used to belong to Mena, you'll see that the end-date of the information is the day _before_ the start date of the information. That's likely an indicator of invalid data.

Comment: They're saving it for when the Playboy mansion gets its own airport.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It looks to me like the [source site](http://airport-codes.wanderbat.com/) you quoted is unreliable or at least not current, e.g. it gives results for codes QQQ and ZZZ too, but they [haven't been assigned by IATA](http://www.iata.org/publications/Pages/code-search.aspx). The actual IATA code for [Mena (ICAO: KMEZ)](http://airnav.com/airport/KMEZ) seems to be MZX.

Anyway, there's no particular reason why [XXX](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/16667/62), ZZZ or any other specific combination should be assigned; they just [haven't been used yet](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/21395/62). There's also no reason why IATA should assign a code to every airport: the US alone [has over 5,000 public airports](http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/publications/national_transportation_statistics/html/table_01_03.html) but only 500 or so have air carrier service.

Comment: If they're smart, XXX will never be assigned.  It's an obvious placeholder for "no code", so there are probably a lot of systems and data out there that will get confused if it ever enters use (see: the experience of people with "NO PLATE" as their vanity license plate).

Comment: @Mark Ah, the classic `'NULL' == NULL` effect.